# Is there a name/algorithm for this graph problem? Expand a grid outward to collect maximum value on edges

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dijkstra, undirected-graph

I'm facing an undirected weighted graph problem that I'm sure has been tackled many times, and I'm wondering if it has a name and existing algorithm. Edges represent value I want to capture and maximize, starting from a subgrid and expanding outward until it's not worth it any more to continue.

Let's say my starting grid is composed of nodes 3 and 5 in the image below. I want to capture the big numbered edges and avoid the small numbered edges. The best greedy move would be to 4 to capture the large 15 edge, now my grid is 3, 5 and 4. The next best move would be connecting 5 to 8 to capture the 12 edge.

[image: Graph]

Now, a greedy algorithm might not connect that huge 20 connection, since it requires a weaker move like 4 to 7 or 2 to 1 first. Could I use something like an A* or Dijkstra's? And as for a stopping point how do I capture the "cost" of expansion? Do I just calculate the length of the segments traveled and compare it to the edge value captured and subtract it from the segment's value?

Comment: Can't see the image, sounds similar to prize-collecting TSP from your description. There are many prize-collection variants of NP-hard optimization problems, so "prize-collecting" is a reasonable keyword for searching the theory literature.

Comment: Fixed. There is no path or traversal order in this case, just a grid expanding until not cost effective. I will look for prize collecting

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you are trying to maximize. If it's the total value on edges, then why not just expand to all edges?

Comment: Ah, more similar to prize-collecting Steiner tree then, but with edge weights instead of node weights. I think we can reduce to p-c Steiner by subdividing each edge and assigning its prize to the new node.

Comment: "And as for a stopping point how do I capture the "cost" of expansion? Do I just calculate the length of the segments traveled and compare it to the edge value captured and subtract it from the segment's value" You might, do that, but then instead of capturing all edges, just capture those with positive `prize - cost` values. Still not very complicated.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That wouldn't work since I might want to take a negative edge at a loss to get to a high value prize edge

Comment: 1) Replace your graph G by its [line-graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) L: every edge of G corresponds to a node in L, and two nodes in L have an edge iff the corresponding edges in G are incident. 2) Solve the [Maximum-Weight Connected Subgraph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824344/maximum-edgeweight-connected-subgraph-of-an-undirected-graph) problem in graph L. 3) Done.